# WooCommerce not showing templates

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi i'm creating a webshop with WooCommerce but with a self made theme, now showing the content-single-template works fine, however the cart/checkout page is not working. This is what i've done so far:

• Add woocommerce.php in the root of my theme with `woocommerce_content()` inside.

• Created "woocommerce" directory in the root of my theme inside this directory another one "checkout" and inside there my custom form-checkout.php

• Shortcodes on every page are included

• Clean install WooCommerce

• Flushed permalinks

I've read trough [this](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/?utm_source=notice&utm_medium=product&utm_content=themecompatibility&utm_campaign=woocommerceplugin) article from WooCommerce on how to integrate it and followed every step precisely.

When i switch to a differend theme it does show the cart/checkout page so wondering what i'm overseeing here.

Thanks

EDIT:

Contents: woocommerce.php

```
<?php
get_header();

woocommerce_content();

get_footer();
```

Comment: • Add woocommerce.php in the root of my theme with woocommerce_content() inside. ==> This is wrong. You must add it to /directory-theme/woocommerce/woocommerce.php

Comment: Thanks for you answer, according to the docs it should be in the root of your theme, however i tried to see if it works and it doesn't.

Comment: And it work or not? I always using this method when I want customize woocomerce that: Copy folders /plugins/woocommerce/templates -> Change name to woocommerce and paste on my theme. xD

Comment: Nope doesn't work :-(

Comment: Can you show content of woocommerce.php and hook you added to functions.php

Comment: See my updated question, there are no hooks in the functions.php because in the docs it said either the woocommerce.php way or through a hook and i  prefer.

Comment: I can see your woocommerce.php missing the loop.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, tried it but it doesn't work, according to the article i provided in my question you should replace the loop with `woocommerce_content()`

Comment: I'm sorry about take your time. I will try it in my sites and help you later.

Comment: No thank you for taking the time haha :-)

Comment: I much prefer the [`hooks`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/#section-2) method for achieving theme compatibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it fixed, because i basically created my own theme i started switching theme's and see the difference between mine and the working theme.

What fixed it for me was in content.php placing this:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The Proper way to work with WooCommerce Templates is, Copy the templates folder from your /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/ and paste it in your theme like /wp-content/themes/your-theme/  and rename it to /woocommerce/ So It would be like this

/wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/ and then you can edit the templates and change the UI.